# Deleting axis in Show

Tags: plotting

Could any one help me to delete the axis when using Show? I tried as below but it didn't work:

```
bj = Show[ 
 {des = PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}], des /. Line[a_] -> {Red, Polygon[a]},des}, 
 {des = PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}, Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}], des /. Line[a_] -> {Blue, Polygon[a]}, des}, 
 {des = PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, Pi, 3 Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}, Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}], des /. Line[a_] -> {Darker[Red], Polygon[a]}, des}, 
 {des = Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.7}]}, Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}], des /. Line[a_] -> {Blue, Polygon[a]}, des}, 
 Axes -> {False, False}
]
```

Comment: It's not an axis, it's the `Frame` you left active when setting `Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}`. You can remove that directive, or add `Frame -> False` to your `Show` options.

Comment: @MarcoB doesn't work: bj = Show[{des = 
    PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> False], 
   des /. Line[a_] -> {Red, Polygon[a]}, 
   des}, {des = 
    PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed},
      Frame -> False], des /. Line[a_] -> {Blue, Polygon[a]}, 
   des}, {des = 
    PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, Pi, 3 Pi/2}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}, Frame -> False], 
   des /. Line[a_] -> {Darker[Red], Polygon[a]}, 
   des}, {des = 
    Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.7}]}, Frame -> False], 
   des /. Line[a_] -> {Blue, Polygon[a]}, des}]

Comment: Add `Axes -> False` as well.

Comment: I wonder also if perhaps you should use `PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]` to apply both directives to the one plot. Otherwise the `Dashed` directive is effectively being ignored. Note also that the repetition of `des` at the end of each list is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Show[
 PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}] /. Line[a_] :> {Red, EdgeForm[{Gray, Dashed}], Polygon[a]},
 PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, 0, Pi/2}] /. Line[a_] :> {Blue, EdgeForm[{Gray, Dashed}], Polygon[a]},
 PolarPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t], {t, Pi, 3 Pi/2}] /. Line[a_] :> {Darker[Red], EdgeForm[{Gray, Dashed}], Polygon[a]},
 Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.7}]}],
 Axes -> False
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there any way to keep axes but delete axes numbers?

Comment: @Monaphys Yes: instead of `Axes -> False`, use `Ticks -> None`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
rep[x_, c_] := x /. Line[a_] -> {c, Polygon[a]};

f = 2.3 Sin[2 t];

Show[
 rep[PolarPlot[f, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, Frame -> False], Red],
 rep[PolarPlot[f, {t, 0, Pi/2}], Blue],
 rep[PolarPlot[f, {t, Pi, 3 Pi/2}], Darker@Red],
 rep[Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.7}]}], Blue]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using a single `ParametricPlot` to produce the same graphics

```
semiaxes = {0.2, .7};
ellipse = Graphics[{White, Disk[{0, 0}, semiaxes]}];
Show[ParametricPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t] r {Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> True, Ticks -> False, Frame -> False, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed],MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},  
  Mesh -> {{0, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2, 2 Pi}}, MeshShading -> {Red, Blue, Red, Darker@Red}], 
 ellipse]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use a single `ParametricPlot` removing the ellipsoid with the option `RegionFunction`:

```
regionfunction = Function[{x, y, u, v}, Plus @@ (({x, y}/semiaxes)^2) >= 1];
ParametricPlot[2.3 Sin[2 t] r {Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> True, Ticks -> False, Frame -> False, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},  
 Mesh -> {{0, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2, 2 Pi}}, MeshShading -> {Red, Blue, Red, Darker@Red},  
 RegionFunction -> regionfunction]
```

[image]